# Convert String Array to xlsx using Apache poi?

Tags: java, spring, performance, apache-poi, sxssf

I want to create xlsx from string array.
I tried to adapt [Convert csv to xls/xlsx using Apache poi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077264/convert-csv-to-xls-xlsx-using-apache-poi) solution, but not clear how to place everything correctly?

```
public void createXlsx(String[] resultSet) {
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet");
    AtomicReference<Integer> row = new AtomicReference<>(0);
    Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(resultSet.length)
            .forEach(i -> sheet.createRow(row.getAndSet(row.get() + 1)).createCell(i).setCellValue(resultSet[i]));
    try {
        OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of("/Documents/test.xlsx"), CREATE_NEW);
        workbook.write(out);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing a stream with a loop solved that issue

```
SXSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++) {
        headerRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(resultSet[i]);
    }
```